# Java multiple menu item with an event listener?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout, listener

I have two menu items here ,one is for the student information and the another one is for the teacher information.i have added the menu for student and teacher both.

I am struck in the event listener how to add the action to the menu  and menu1,suppose when the user click on menu 1 then student information should be displayed and for the menu2 the teacher information action should be performed.i am confused where to add the action listenr and perform the operation for the student and teacher.

I am new to the the event and action listner in java.kindly suggest the solution

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class Searchdb extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

//Initializing Components
    JLabel lb,lbd,lb1, lb2, lb3, lb5;
    JTextField tf1, tf2,tf3,tf5,tfd;
    JButton btn;
 JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu menu = new JMenu("Student");
    JMenu menu1 = new JMenu("Teacher");
    //Creating Constructor for initializing JFrame components
    Searchdb() {
        //Providing Title
        super("Fetching Roll Information");

        setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        menuBar.add(menu);
        menuBar.add(menu1);


        lb5 = new JLabel("Roll Number:");
        lb5.setBounds(20, 20, 100, 20);
        tf5 = new JTextField(20);
        tf5.setBounds(130, 20, 200, 20);

        lbd = new JLabel("Date:");
        lbd.setBounds(20, 50, 100, 20);
        tfd = new JTextField(20);
        tfd.setBounds(130, 50, 200, 20);


        btn = new JButton("Submit");
        btn.setBounds(50, 50, 100, 20);
        btn.addActionListener(this);

        lb = new JLabel("Fetching Student Information From Database");
        lb.setBounds(30, 80, 450, 30);
        lb.setForeground(Color.black);
        lb.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(500, 500);

        lb1 = new JLabel("Name:");
        lb1.setBounds(20, 120, 100, 20);
        tf1 = new JTextField(50);
        tf1.setBounds(130, 120, 200, 20);
        lb2 = new JLabel("Fathername:");
        lb2.setBounds(20, 150, 100, 20);
        tf2 = new JTextField(100);
        tf2.setBounds(130, 150, 200, 20);
        lb3 = new JLabel("State:");
        lb3.setBounds(20, 180, 100, 20);
        tf3 = new JTextField(50);
        tf3.setBounds(130, 180, 200, 20);

        setLayout(null);

        //Add components to the JFrame
        add(lb5);
        add(tf5);
        add(lbd);
        add(tfd);
        add(btn);

        add(lb);
        add(lb1);
        add(tf1);
        add(lb2);
        add(tf2);
        add(lb3);
        add(tf3);


        //Set TextField Editable False
        tf1.setEditable(false);
        tf2.setEditable(false);
        tf3.setEditable(false);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //Create DataBase Coonection and Fetching Records

        try {
            String str = tf5.getText();

            Datestri = tfd.getText();//Getting the unable to convert String to Date error

            System.out.println(str);
            System.out.println(stri);

            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//host:port/servicename","username","password");
            PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("select Name,Fathername,State from student_db where roll_number=? and medium=?");
            System.out.println(st);
            st.setString(1, str);
            st.setDate(2, stri);



            //Excuting Query
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
            System.out.println(rs);

            if (rs.next()) {
                String s = rs.getString(1);
                String s1 = rs.getString(2);
                String s2 = rs.getString(3);


                //Sets Records in TextFields.
                tf1.setText(s);
                tf2.setText(s1);
                tf3.setText(s2);

            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Student not Found");
            }

            //Create Exception Handler
        } catch (Exception ex) {

            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //Create DataBase Coonection and Fetching Records

        //Teacher information should be retrieved from the db

        }

//Running Constructor

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Searchdb();
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope, This will help

For JMenu you can use MenuListener

```
class MenuListenerAdapter implements MenuListener {

    @Override
    public void menuSelected(MenuEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Menu Selected");
    }

    @Override
    public void menuDeselected(MenuEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Menu Deselected");
    }

    @Override
    public void menuCanceled(MenuEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Menu Canceled");
    }
}
```

Then add MenuListener on  menu

```
menu.addMenuListener(new MenuListenerAdapter());
```

Comment: could you please tell me exactly in my code where to add the listener.it will be more helpful @Pradnyarani

Comment: in the constructor Searchdb()

Answer (score 1):

**You can use MouseListener,
Find your solution below, check out console when you click on Student and Teacher Menu**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Searchdb extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    //Initializing Components
    JLabel lb, lbd, lb1, lb2, lb3, lb5;

    JTextField tf1, tf2, tf3, tf5, tfd;

    JButton btn;

    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();

    JMenu menu = new JMenu("Student");

    JMenu menu1 = new JMenu("Teacher");

    //Creating Constructor for initializing JFrame components
    Searchdb() {
        //Providing Title
        super("Fetching Roll Information");

        setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        menuBar.add(menu);
        menuBar.add(menu1);

        menu.addMouseListener(new MouseListenerForStudentAndTeacher());
        menu1.addMouseListener(new MouseListenerForStudentAndTeacher());

        lb5 = new JLabel("Roll Number:");
        lb5.setBounds(20, 20, 100, 20);
        tf5 = new JTextField(20);
        tf5.setBounds(130, 20, 200, 20);

        lbd = new JLabel("Date:");
        lbd.setBounds(20, 50, 100, 20);
        tfd = new JTextField(20);
        tfd.setBounds(130, 50, 200, 20);

        btn = new JButton("Submit");
        btn.setBounds(50, 50, 100, 20);
        btn.addActionListener(this);

        lb = new JLabel("Fetching Student Information From Database");
        lb.setBounds(30, 80, 450, 30);
        lb.setForeground(Color.black);
        lb.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(500, 500);

        lb1 = new JLabel("Name:");
        lb1.setBounds(20, 120, 100, 20);
        tf1 = new JTextField(50);
        tf1.setBounds(130, 120, 200, 20);
        lb2 = new JLabel("Fathername:");
        lb2.setBounds(20, 150, 100, 20);
        tf2 = new JTextField(100);
        tf2.setBounds(130, 150, 200, 20);
        lb3 = new JLabel("State:");
        lb3.setBounds(20, 180, 100, 20);
        tf3 = new JTextField(50);
        tf3.setBounds(130, 180, 200, 20);

        setLayout(null);

        //Add components to the JFrame
        add(lb5);
        add(tf5);
        add(lbd);
        add(tfd);
        add(btn);

        add(lb);
        add(lb1);
        add(tf1);
        add(lb2);
        add(tf2);
        add(lb3);
        add(tf3);

        //Set TextField Editable False
        tf1.setEditable(false);
        tf2.setEditable(false);
        tf3.setEditable(false);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        // removed code, you can add your code later on
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        new Searchdb();
    }

    private class MouseListenerForStudentAndTeacher extends MouseAdapter {

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

            if (e.getSource() == menu) {
                System.out.println("Student Menu Clicked");
            }
            if (e.getSource() == menu1) {
                System.out.println("Teacher Menu Clicked");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sure@Nilesh Jadav

Comment: I am getting the output in console when the menu bar is clicked for Student and teacher.
my problem is when i click on the teacher menu (menu2) then menu should not displayed in the screen.

when i press menu (student information ) then menu2 should not be displayed with the content @Nilesh Jadav